# camelCase POST data in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, camelcasing

I see there is project called [djangorestframework-camel-case](https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case), which allows to use JavaScript-ish camelCase with underscore_cased fields in Django REST serializers. So, basically, I can send:

```
{
    "camelCase": "foo"
}
```

And receive it with following Serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    session_id = serializers.CharField()
```

Does something similar for POST data exist? So I can send `camelCase=foo` via POST and receive it to an underscore_case field in my serializer?

I tried implementing my own parser based on FormParser:

```
class CamelCaseFormParser(FormParser):
    media_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    def __init__(self):
        print("initialized")

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        print("parse")
        ...
```

And, after adding it to `DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES` in settings.py, while `initialized` is actually printed, `parse` is not. So it seems, in case of POST data, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parser is not used at all.

Since Serializers are used like that:

```
Serializer(data=request.data)
```

I'm thinking about subclassing Serializer and modifying `data` before it gets processed further, or even modifying it before creating a Serializer. But what I'm asking for is a more convenient way, working for all Serializers, without subclassing them.

Comment: Did you found a better solution? I do not understand what other developers does with this issue.

Answer (score 6):

why not sticking with parsers?

```
from djangorestframework_camel_case.util import underscoreize
from rest_framework import parsers
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import QueryDict


class CamelCaseFormParser(parsers.FormParser):
    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        parser_context = parser_context or {}
        encoding = parser_context.get('encoding', settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
        data = QueryDict(stream.read(), encoding=encoding)
        return underscoreize(data)
```

simple, working and properly placed...

Comment: Thanks for this snippet!! Still worth it.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioSánchez Is this the latest things that you come up with? A better simpler solution? Should I tell my client side to add the converter and I stick to my pythonic API?